# JPA Query Unexpected AST node:=

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, jpa

My Code is failing to compile after I add the following JPQL query to my repository as it seems like it has a problem with d.car c clause:

```
public interface DriverRepository extends CrudRepository<DriverDO, Long>
{

    @Query("SELECT d FROM DriverDO d JOIN d.car WHERE (d.username = :username || :username is null) "
            + "and (d.onlineStatus = :onlineStatus || :onlineStatus is null) "
            + "and (d.onlineStatus = :onlineStatus || :onlineStatus is null) "
            + "and (c.licensePlate = :licensePlate || :licensePlate is null) "
            + "and (c.rating = :rating || :rating is null) "
            + "and (c.convertible = :convertible || :convertible is null) "
            + "and (c.engineType = :engineType || :engineType is null) ")
    List<DriverDO> findDriversByAttributes(@Param("username") String username, 
            @Param("onlineStatus") OnlineStatus onlineStatus,
            @Param("licensePlate") String licensePlate,
            @Param("rating") Integer rating,
            @Param("convertible") Boolean convertible,
            @Param("engineType") EngineType engineType);
}
```

I have looked everywhere on internet and it seems the syntax I'm suing is correct as I want to join with a car in my entity.

Following are my Entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(
    name = "driver",
    uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(name = "uc_username", columnNames = {"username"})
)
public class DriverDO
{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @NotNull(message = "Username can not be null!")
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @NotNull(message = "Password can not be null!")
    private String password;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private OnlineStatus onlineStatus;

    /** One to one relationship with car */
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "car_id", nullable = true)
    private CarDO car;
    ...
```

Car Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(
    name = "car",
    uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(name = "uc_license_plate", columnNames = {"license_plate"})
)
public class CarDO {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "license_plate", nullable = false)
    @NotNull(message = "License plate can not be null!")
    private String licensePlate;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Boolean convertible;

    private Integer rating;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "engine_type", nullable = false)
    private EngineType engineType;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "car", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private DriverDO driver;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "manufacturer_id", nullable = false)
    private ManufacturerDO manufacturer;

    private CarDO() {
    }
    ...
}
```

I have tried numerous ways to construct the query but none seems to be working so far. I don't know how I should be able to make the join work. What I'm trying to accomplish here is I have a bunch of optional parameters that I get in my REST GET method and I'm trying to search on parameters that are being passed by matching if they are not null. I don't know if I my approach is right but so far I can't even get the code to compile let alone came with a solution. Also you may think I have done an error by making car in driver entity as nullable but it's a requirement as driver can exist without a car and car can be without a driver but only one car could belong to a driver.

Here's the error I get:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: = near line 1, column 79 [SELECT d FROM com.mytaxi.domainobject.DriverDO d JOIN d.car WHERE (d.username = :username || :username is null) and (d.onlineStatus = :onlineStatus || :onlineStatus is null) and (d.onlineStatus = :onlineStatus || :onlineStatus is null) and (c.licensePlate = :licensePlate || :licensePlate is null) and (c.rating = :rating || :rating is null) and (c.convertible = :convertible || :convertible is null) and (c.engineType = :engineType || :engineType is null) and (c.manufacturer = :manufacturer || :manufacturer is null) ]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:272) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:141) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:553) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:662) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    ... 81 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Jpa doesn't use || for OR.

Comment: Okay got it, very silly of me. Make it your answer so I can mark it as answer.